# Extend / override Mapbox-gl 'baselayer' loadTile

Tags: raster, leaflet, wms, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Similar to how Leaflet's [guide](https://leafletjs.com/examples/extending/extending-2-layers.html) shows how to override L.TileLayer's `getTileUrl` method in place of your own (and L.GridLayer's `createTile` method),

I want to know how to extend/override Mapbox-gl's baselayer tiles (as opposed to only using a [tile server URL](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/map-tiles/) to add in custom tiles).

I'm looking to avoid just [adding a layer](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#addlayer) and instead want to overwrite the baselayer itself.

I saw [this issue discussion](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/3186) of customizing RasterTileSource.loadTile and wondered if this was the right direction.

Leaflet's example:

```
L.TileLayer.Kitten = L.TileLayer.extend({
    getTileUrl: function(coords) {
        var i = Math.ceil( Math.random() * 4 );
        return "https://placekitten.com/256/256?image=" + i;
    }
});

L.tileLayer.kitten = function() {
    return new L.TileLayer.Kitten();
}

L.tileLayer.kitten().addTo(map);
```